# Recreating the look and feel of WP7 Metro UI using CSS3, HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: windows, html, windows-phone-7, css, microsoft-metro

Are there any examples out there that can create/recreate the common Metro UI controls using CSS/javascript/HTML5 for Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shameless plug: https://github.com/ace-subido/css3-microsoft-metro-buttons try using this CSS/JS library for metro-buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some simple examples here:

[Developing Windows Phone 7 HTML5 apps with PhoneGap](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/09/developing-windows-phone-7-html5-apps-with-phonegap/)

Try the following to get you started:

```
body, input, div, span
{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Segoe WP, Sans-Serif;
}

body
{
    background:black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

h2
{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 32px; /* PhoneFontSizeLarge */
}

h1
{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 42.667px; /* PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge */
}

button
{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid white; /* PhoneBorderThickness */
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size: 25.333px; /* PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge */
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}

button:active
{
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

button:disabled
{
  opacity: 0.7;
}

input[type="text"]
{
  font-size: 25.333px; /* PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge */
  width: 200px;
  padding: 6px;
    height: 31px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    color: black;
}

input[type="checkbox"]
{
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```